# Finding one transposition permutation from a list in Python and C

Tags: python, c, list

I have the input as `A = [ 2,3,4,1]`

The output is simply all possible permutation from elements in A which can be done by single transposition (single flip of two neighbouring elements) operation. So the output is :

```
[3,2,4,1],[ 2,4,3,1],[2,3,1,4],[1,3,4,2]
```

How to do this in Python? and/or **C**?

**EDIT**
Circular transpositioning is allowed. Hence `[2,3,4,1]` ==> `[1,3,4,2]` is allowed and a valid output.

Comment: Is `A` supposed to be a circular buffer? Why are the first and last elements (2 and 1) transposed in the last list in your output?

Comment: @mhawke we should assume so

Comment: Yes. Circular transpositioning is allowed. Hence [2,3,4,1] ==> [1,3,4,2] is allowed and a valid output.

Comment: have you made any attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an *out-of-box* solution but quite trivial and simple to understand

```
a = [ 2,3,4,1]                           # Initialize the array with input
o = []                                   # Have a empty list to hold the output
n = len(a)                               # Get the length of the array
for i in range(n):                       # Loop 'n' times 
    x=a[:]                               # Get a copy of the array. '[:]' is the  slicing operator. '[:]' means to copy all the elements of the list to 'x'
    x[i],x[(i+1)%n] = x[(i+1)%n],x[i]    # Swap the adjacent two elements. We require '%' modulus operator to make the list circular
    o.append(x)                          # Add the changed list to the output array
print o                                  # Print the output array
```

The output is

```
[[3, 2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1, 4], [1, 3, 4, 2]]
```

Comment: I quite didn't understand the flow here though it works fine. x=a[:] does what?

Comment: @Technopolice `x=a[:]` assigns a copy of list a instead of assigning its reference so that at every iteration x is having fresh copy of list x. Try assigning `x=a` you will see different results as list a will keep on changing because `x[i],x[(i+1)%n] = x[(i+1)%n],x[i]` is swapping the elements of list a.

Comment: @Technopolice Whatever Tanveer has said is the correct explanation. Do check the comments added.

Answer (score 5):

```
A = [2,3,4,1]

res = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    temp = A[:]
    temp[i], temp[i-1] = temp[i-1], temp[i]
    res.append(temp)

print res
```

Results:

```
[[1, 3, 4, 2], [3, 2, 4, 1], [2, 4, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1, 4]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def swapped(l, p1, p2):
    r = l[:]
    r[p1], r[p2] = r[p2], r[p1]
    return r

A = [2, 3, 4, 1]
transp = [swapped(A, i, (i+1)%len(A)) for i in range(len(A))]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something a little different:

```
def swapper(a, j, k):
    return [a[k] if i == j else a[j] if i == k else a[i] for i in range(len(a))]

def transpositions(a):
    length = len(a)
    return [swapper(a, j, (j+1)%length) for j in range(length)]

print(transpositions([2, 3, 4, 1]))
```

Here's a more iterative solution:

```
from itertools import izip, tee

def swaps(length):
    a, b = tee(range(length))
    next(b, None)
    for pair in izip(a, b):
        yield pair
    yield (length-1, 0)

def swapper(a, i, j):
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]
    yield a
    a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i]

def transpositions(a):
    return [r for i, j in swaps(len(a)) for r in swapper(a, i, j)]

print(transpositions([2, 3, 4, 1]))
```